# IIS reverse proxy with Windows Auth throwing intermittent 502 errors

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, windows-authentication

I have set up a web site (www.mysite.com) on IIS to provide SSL and Windows Auth, and to forward all HTTPS requests to another server (BIOS name: internalserver; port 2080). The rule specifying this setup reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://InternalServer:2080/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is leading to the following behavior (reproducible in both IExplorer and Firefox):

- Clicking www.mysite.com results in Error 502 "Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server"
- Reloading the page causes the site to load - but unformatted, suggesting that the CSS files were not found.
- Reloading the page a second time causes the site to load correctly, including CSS-specified formats.

The Error 502 reappears each time the browser is closed and relaunched.

On the other hand, if I use Basic Auth instead of Windows Auth, the reverse proxy works just fine, with none of the above issues coming up.

My question are:

- is the emergence of Error 502 known in this type of configuration known?
- does this represent a bug in IIS?
- if not, is any interaction with other software known to produce this issue?