# IIS: selective access to folders

Tags: iis, authentication, authorization

Site MyGreatCompany.com is served by an IIS webserver through SSL and basic authentication.

The root directory and all subdirectories should be accessible to every authenticated user, except for subdirectory /wwwroot/yearlyperformancereviews/ (and all its subdirectories) which should only be accessible for members of the group "HR_Creeps".

How can I restrict access to the folder /wwwroot/yearlyperformancereviews/ as specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the appropriate NTFS permissions on the folders in question.

Comment: meaning that I cannot do it with Basic Authenthication?

Comment: Actually, basic will work too, but Windows auth is nicer since you get SSO.

Comment: thanks. I would love to use Windows Auth, but I got nothing but trouble when I tried. See this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/462077/iis-reverse-proxy-with-windows-auth-throwing-intermittent-502-errors